# Call a remote javascript function and bind it to a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a js file in remote server and this is it.

```
function findAllModules() {
    return {
        ModuleNames: [
            'Mandate',
            'AppStore',
            'IdeaMart'
        ]
    };
}

function allServices(moduleName) {
    switch (moduleName) {
        default :
            return {
                serviceNames: [
                    'getPort',
                    'gethost',
                    'getDiscoveryApiTimeout'
                ]
            }
    }
}

function getServiceData(moduleName, serviceName){
    return {
        moduleName : moduleName,
        serviceName : serviceName,
        data : {
            port : 1122
        }
    }
}

function updateServiceData(moduleName, serviceName, data){
    return "Done " + moduleName + serviceName + data
}
```

I want to call this file's getServiceData function. Then that should be bound to a angularjs contraller. How can I get this thing done.

Answer (score 1):

If the JavaScript file is adding those functions to the global scope then you could wrap those global methods in a service

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.service('dataService', [function(){

    var getServiceData = function(moduleName, serviceName){
        return window.getServiceData(moduleName, serviceName);
    };

    return {
        getServiceData: getServiceData
    };

}]);
```

In your controller you would inject the service

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', 'dataService', function($scope, dataService){

     $scope.serverData = dataService.getServerData('moduleName', 'serviceName');
}]);
```